# What to learn in order to understand Weil Divisors

Tags: pairings

My current role as a software developer is leading into areas of research in elliptic-curve-cryptography that keeps bringing me back to bilinear pairings.  This includes BLS Signatures, CL Signatures and zkSnarks.

In learning PBC, I've found I need to understand Miller's algorithm, but I lack the mathematical background to fully understand the concepts of divisors, (zeros and poles on elliptic curves etc.)

Has anyone faced this issue? If so, can you save me possibly weeks of work, and point me in the direction of accessible resources that I should digest in order to understand Weil divisors?

*Is it possible to understand the required theory without learning linear algebra / abstract algebra and algebraic geometry?*